# Contracting nodes with self-loops in networkx

Tags: python, python-3.x, networkx

I noticed an inconsistency in the behavior of `networkx.contracted_nodes(G,u,v)`. The function is expected to contract (merge) nodes `u` and `v` in the graph `G`, which it does - as long as neither `u` nor `v` have a self-loop edge. If a loop is present, the function removes the self-loop instead of merging the nodes. Example:

```
G = nx.Graph([(1,1), (1,2), (2,2)]) # Two nodes
H = nx.contracted_nodes(G, 1, 2, self_loops=False)
H.edges() # Should be one node now
```

Output:

```
[(1, 1), (1, 2)] # Nope, same two nodes, but only one edge
```

Is this a bug, undefined behavior or an undocumented feature?

[Current documentation](http://networkx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.minors.contracted_nodes.html#networkx.algorithms.minors.contracted_nodes)

P.S. The bug was fixed in 2.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a bug to me.  FWIW, it occurs even without the (1,1) edge in `G`. 
 In the [source code](https://networkx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/networkx/algorithms/minors.html#contracted_nodes), for an undirected graph it does

```
new_edges = ((u, w, d) for x, w, d in G.edges(v, data=True)
                 if self_loops or w != u)
```

In your case `u` is `1` and `w` is `2`.  It is looping through all edges of the form `(v,w,d)` with `x` always equal to `v`, `w` is the other node in the edge and `d` is the data for the edge (in your case nothing).

When it comes to the `(2,2)` edge, it adds an edge between `u` which is `1` and `w` which is `2`.  This causes `2` to be a node in the new graph.

So it needs to handle the case `w == v` better.

I've added a [bug report](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/issues/2575).

---

**EDIT** It appears this bug will be fixed by the next release which is coming soon.